# Protractor- automate the error message on tab out when input field is empty

Tags: protractor, angular2-forms

I have an angular2 application where I am trying to write end to end test cases to automate things.I have just begun with learning Protractor for this and trying to implement a negative test case for a form field where if any field is empty, the error message should be shown. I have tried something like below to automate the form and its working fine.
In my spec.ts-

```
import userDetailsPage from './userDetails.e2e-po;

    it('should fill out User Details', () => {
          const userDetail: IUserDetail = {
            firstName: 'Lorem',
            lastName: 'Ipsum'
          };

          userDetailsPage.populateUserDetails(userDetail);
        });
```

In userDetails.e2e-po-

```
populateUserDetails(details: IUserDetail) {
    this.fillFirstName(details.firstName)
      .fillLastName(details.lastName)
     return this;
  }
```

I am writing the below code which automatically inputs the firstName and lastName field.

```
fillLastName(last: string) {
    let el = element(by.css('input[name="lastName'));
    el.clear().then(() => {
      el.sendKeys(last);
    });
    return this;
  }
```

The above scenario works fine. But I am also trying to achieve a scenario where I do not input either first name or last name field, should throw me an error message.Can someone let me know what else should I add to achieve this.

I am already handling the validation in my HTML.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of details.firstname and details.lastname put empty strings and then validate the error that occurs on the page.

Comment: yeah, that's happening but the error is displayed the moment its tabbed out or moved to the next filed.I want the control to go back and fill in the input then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following method as a reusable function

```
 function formValidate(donefn){
   newProjBtn.click().then(async function () {
     var lastName_fld = element(by.css('input[name="lastName'));
       await lastName_fld.sendKeys("", protractor.Key.TAB);
       //browser.sleep(2000);
        var elm = element(by.css(".error-message"));
        elm.isPresent().then(function(result){
          if(result){
            console.log("Error message displayed")
             //some more code to do like selecting the field and enter the test
            return result;
          }else{
            console.log("Error message not displayed")
            return result;
          }
        })
     donefn();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

```
      await input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a');
      await input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
      await input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
//then the error-message will appear
```